# Unnest/Unlist moving window results in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe that has two columns, x and y (both populated with numbers). I am trying to look at a moving window within the data, and I've done it like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948482/r-moving-window-to-extract-subsets-of-dataframe-and-store-them-in-a-list-of-dat)):

```
# Extract just x and y from the original data frame
df <- dat_fin %>% select(x, y)

# Moving window creation
nr <- nrow(df)
windowSize <- 10
windfs <- lapply(seq_len(nr - windowSize + 1), function(i) df[i:(i + windowSize - 1), ])
```

This `lapply` creates a list of tibbles that are each 10 (x, y) pairs. At this point, I am trying to compute a single quantity using each of the sets of 10 pairs; my current (not working) code looks like this:

```
library(shotGroups)
for (f in 1:length(windfs)) {
  tsceps[f] = getCEP(windfs[f], accuracy = TRUE)
}
```

When I run this, I get the error:

`Error in getCEP.default(windfs, accuracy = TRUE) : xy must be numeric`

My goal is that the variable that I've called `tsceps` should be a 1 x `length(windfs)` data frame, each value in which comes from the `getCEP` calculation for each of the windowed subsets.

I've tried various things with `unnest` and `unlist`, all of which were unsuccessful.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
df <- dat_fin %>% select(x, y)

nr <- nrow(df)
windowSize <- 10
windfs <- lapply(seq_len(nr - windowSize + 1), function(i) df[i:(i + windowSize - 1), ])

tsceps <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(windfs))

library(shotGroups)

for (j in 1:length(windfs)) {
  tsceps[j] <- getCEP(windfs[[j]], type = "CorrNormal", CEPlevel = 0.50, accuracy = TRUE)
}

ults <- unlist(tsceps)

ults_cep <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(ults))

for (k in 1:length(ults)) {
  ults_cep[k] <- ults[[k]]
}
```

To get this working with multiple `type` arguments to `getCEP`, just use additional code blocks for each `type` required.

Comment: Why would you post this as a solution if it is still not working?

Comment: also you ca use `zoo::rollapply`

Comment: @onyambu - I made it work by adding similar code blocks for each method used.

Comment: You do not need the last `for loop` just a simple `ults <- unlist(tsceps, FALSE)` should suffice